# Identifying tenant ID on IoT Edge

Tags: cumulocity

I've set up Cumulocity's IoT Edge locally with domain example.edge.com, I can login and everything is functioning fine.  I'm trying to create a device using Postman, or use any REST API using Postman, but I can't base64 encode my credentials ok because I can't get my tenant ID correct. For base64 encoding, I know my username and password, but how do I find my tenant ID for the IoT Edge, with local domain example.edge.com?

I use this format to base64 encode:

"tenantID/username:password"

Answer (score 1):

Found it.  In the response of a POST to url/deviceControl/newDeviceRequest the json has:

tenantID:"edge"

All is well.

Answer (score 1):

Edge is set up with predefined TenantID/TeanatName and that is "edge"